# Randomize materials using python

Tags: python, texturing, materials, scripting

Blender beginner here.

I am currently working on a project for which I am making a synthetic dataset involving a chess board and its pieces.

[image: Render of chess board]

To give this modell the variation it needs I would like to randomize both the material/ texture of the board and pieces using python. I have seen some posts about randomly assigning materials from a pre-existing list, but none about creating them through a script.

[image: materials tab]

What I've been doing is just assigning a random number to these values under the material section.

A friend of mine told me automating the creation/ changing of materials doesn't work well in blender and this is the most I could do. (hence why there are not many questions about creating materials, instead rather about assigning premade ones)
Is this true? They wouldn't need to be too complex. Just some simple patterns and surface structure to distinguish each picture from another would be enough.

Thanks for helping in advance :)

Comment: you can easily create materials and randomize these values with a script but it doesn't make any sense because the output would not look good. you need to know what material you want to create, is it metalic, plastic, specular, transparent, etc... just randomly putting together numbers won't get you good results as creating a material with experimentation.